# Use only filetype in Batch without name

Tags: php, batch-file, cmd

How can I build an Auto Uploader which always upload a CSV file. They have totally different names. I would like to upload just the latest CSV File.

Is there a way to upload it just by using their filetype if only one file of the type exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a batch like this if you want to get the newest csv file :

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir c:\temp\*.csv /B /O:-D') do call:test %%i

:test
echo uploading %1
goto eof

:eof
rem pause to see the execution
pause 
exit
```